# Erlang 19 using multicast

Tags: networking, erlang, multicast

Having the issue here.
Using Erlang 18.3 and 19.3 version on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 built with kerl.
Using module from [Erlang Multicast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78826/erlang-multicast) work as expected using Erlang 18.3 but after activation of 19.3 no packets arriving.
Sending using socat

```
echo hi | socat - UDP4-SENDTO:224.0.0.251:5353
```

Content processing is not important at the moment, the issue with getting the packet.

Comment: By the way, that address is a link-local multicast that is registered for mDNS, and you should not use it for something else.

Comment: Yes I know, the purpose is to see packets, not content or actual implementation yet.

Comment: Going further in investigation:
the same code, with Erlang 19.3, debian (https://hub.docker.com/_/erlang/)
works as expected!
Allocating the issue more precisely - Erlang 19 + macOS