# How do I send a message to multiple processes

Tags: erlang, elixir

I need to send a message to multiple processes at once. Is there a way to do this, without looping over all the PID's and sending the message to each process individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way that does not involve iteration, whether direct (you write it) or indirect (a lib does it for you)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in series with a `for` loop

```
for pid <- listofPids do
   send pid, {:message, self() } 
end
```

the `self()` provides the receiving process with the pid of the message sender.

Glossary: pid = *process id*

If you are prepared to call Erlang from Elixir there is a relevant question here:
[Erlang Multicast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78826/erlang-multicast)

Comment: Yes of course, but I wondered if there was a better way, similar to a UDP broadcast, or something like that.

Comment: best to have put that in your title, then.

Comment: sorry, I thought I had made it clear in the question.

Comment: Have a look at this Erlang example that could be executed from Elixir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78826/erlang-multicast

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you call “message.” For the message that is passed to the process mailbox, the answers are already given.

Also, there is Elixir core [`Registry`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html) module that implements exactly what do you want (basically [`PubSub`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html#module-using-as-a-pubsub).)

If that is a possible way for you to go, you might want to look at [`Envío`](https://hexdocs.pm/envio) library I wrote to simplify publishers and subscribers creation and eliminate all the boilerplate needed.